# how to assign external style to the primeNG <p-column> in angular4

Tags: html, css, angular

If I use internal CSS for  for background color padding adjustment working fine. I want to assign external CSS in Angular 4.
The code using internal css is as follow:

HTML:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="facility"  [globalFilter]="gb" #dt>
   <p-column field="action" header=""></p-column>
   <p-column field="Goal" header="Goal" ></p-column>
   <p-column   class="datatable" field="day1" header="8/1" [style]="{'padding': '4px 0px'}" >
              <template pTemplate let-col let-data="rowData" >
                   <span [ngClass]="{'error': (data[col.field] <= 72),'warning':( 80 >= data[col.field] && data[col.field] >72), 'success':(data[col.field]>80)}" >{{ data[col.field] }}</span>
              </template>
   </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

CSS:

```
.error {
  background-color: red !important;
    padding-bottom: 47%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    padding-left: 37%;
    padding-right: 100%;
}

.warning{
    background-color:yellow !important;
    padding-bottom: 47%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    padding-left: 37%;
    padding-right: 100%;
}

.success{
    background-color:green !important;
    padding-bottom: 47%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    padding-left: 37%;
    padding-right: 100%;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to change style from CSS file mentioned in below section right ?If I am not wrong you trying to change p-column style using class - datatable?

Comment: So you kept the <template> pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add classes inside element of datatable you should use :host selector:

```
:host /deep/ .ui-datatable {
}
```

Wrap your css classes with this lines above.

More about component styles and host selector: 
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host